# Agda standard library - why are more properties not marked abstract?

Tags: abstract, standard-library, agda

Having been working in Agda for the last few months, I've just come across the `abstract` block in Agda which prevents further normalisation of the term outside the scope of the block.

Using it to hide the workings of my lemmas has *greatly* reduced the time required to type-check my programs. Looking through the Agda Standard Library however `abstract` is barely used. It seems to me that almost everything within any `Properties` file (for instance `Data.Nat.Properties`) could be within an `abstract` block, as I can't think of a use for reasoning about, for example, how addition is proved to be commutative.

Is this a case of abstract being a new feature which hasn't made its way into the standard library? Or is there some subtlety or downside of marking proofs `abstract` that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`abstract` is for abstract things, it blocks computation, so if you place proofs in an `abstract` block, you won't be able to use them in `subst` or `rewrite` while still retaining canonicity:

```
module _ where

open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Fin hiding (_+_)

abstract
  +0 : ∀ n -> n + 0 ≡ n
  +0  0      = refl
  +0 (suc n) = cong suc (+0 n)

zero′ : ∀ n -> Fin (suc n + 0)
zero′ n = subst (Fin ∘ suc) (sym (+0 n)) zero

fail : zero′ 2 ≡ zero
fail = refl

-- subst ((λ {.x} → Fin) ∘ suc) (sym (+0 2)) zero != zero of type Fin (suc 2 + 0)
-- when checking that the expression refl has type zero′ 2 ≡ zero
```

I.e. an `abstract` block has the same effect as a `postulate` block.

If you replace `abstract` with `module _ where`, the file will type check.

Andreas Abel [wrote](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/1485#issuecomment-129031107):

> I think this "abstract" feature is little understood.  We should
>   schedule it  for removal, giving a grace period of say 5 years.  If no
>   one has a written a  technical paper about it until 2020, with a
>   proper semantics and a description  of its intended interaction with
>   metas, we drop it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! But if there is (perhaps) a plan to drop `abstract` , is there an alternative feature being proposed to help with performance? I understand that abstraction through records is always a good idea, but in my case the records would have to be enormous and would do a great job of obfuscate my code, as logically they would only be being introduced for performance reasons.

Comment: @user2667523, I don't know. Currently, you can use [`erase`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/f6212e49760a9fc2392b3d0889c8c7fc5e77634b/src/Relation/Binary/PropositionalEquality/TrustMe.agda#L25), if you don't want to compute expensive proofs (and it doesn't mess with canonicity).

Comment: Can [`proof-irrelevance`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.html#1420) be used in `zero′` to get around the problem with `+0 n` being abstract?

Comment: @Cactus, it's strict in both arguments, so I don't think it can be of any use here. You can [abuse](http://lpaste.net/168990) the rewriting machinery, but [it's not safe](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/2432).